# Thread(sqlservr*)\ % Processer Time exceeds 100%

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-administration, windows-server, perfmon

I am writing a powershell script to figure out the CPU Utilization each stored procedure or SQL Query is taking. For that purpose I'm figuring out the SQL Server threads whose CPU Percent is greater than threshold (80%) and then finding those queries.

What I figured out that some of the SQL Utilization for Queries are beyond 100%. I know that this is because of multi cores and multi threading nature of the system, but I want this value to be exact, i.e., below 100% and show the actual value it is using for all the cores.

This is what I'm using

```
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$PerfCounter = "Thread(sqlservr*)\% Processor Time"

$MaxSamples = 5

$ThreadData = Get-Counter  -Counter $PerfCounter -ComputerName $ComputerName -MaxSamples $MaxSamples -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Can anyone help me out in getting this value to be absolute - that is below 100%

Comment: You can judge more/less expensive with those numbers. Does your task at hand actually need that those "percentage" values be less than 100?

Comment: Yes. I need to prepare a report to be handed over which must include which procs or queries use how much CPU %

Comment: Can you simply treat "100%" as 100 x [number of cores], and work off percentages based on that? ie if you have 8 cores, and one query uses 112%, yould calculate as 112 / 800 = 14% ?

Comment: I'll resort to that finally, but was thinking if I could get things sorted automatically within the script.